# Use the power-set construction to find a deterministic automata

Tags: computer-science, automata

Given a nondeterministc automata N, how do you use the power-set construction to find a deterministic automata that recognizes L(N)?

[image]

Here is my work so far:  We can start in state 1, 2. If we get an a, we're in state 2, 3, 4 (which is accepting). If we get a b, we reject (because there's no where to go).

Here's where I'm getting confused: If we're in state 2, 3, 4 and get an a, we can stay in that state (but wouldn't we need to reject if we got an a in 4 because there's no where to go?) And if we're in state 2, 3, 4 and get a b, wouldn't we reject if we got that b in state 2, since there's no where to go? Wouldn't we only go to state 1, 3 if we got an b in state's 3 or 4?

I guess I don't really understand how combining states works in these transition diagrams. Can anyone explain it?

An update:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are in state $\{2,3,4\}$, on input $a$ you can go to $\{2,3\}$, because those are the only states reachable from states $2$, $3$, and $4$ on input $a$.

Similarly, if you are in state $\{2,3,4\}$, on input $b$ you can go to $\{1,2,3\}$, because those are the states that can be reached in the NFA on input $b$ from $2$, $3$, and $4$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I just posted an update with my current diagram, which looks messy but I think it's correct.

Comment: I have another Q though: since 2 is an accepting state, aren't all states that have 2 in them accepting states? Because in that case, every state except R (the rejection state) would be accepting

Comment: That's correct, $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ should be accepting states.